# Divide array into parts into list of list

Tags: c#

I am trying to divide array called "UWeights" to small parts and store them into list of list. The size of each part is stored in array called "Noofelement".
So i wrote the following code for doing this task but there is an exception fired with this title "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" but i don not know what is the problem.

```
     List<List<int>> unknownvalues=new List<List<int>>();

     int stindx = 0;
     int loopiteration = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int nofelement = Noofelement[i];
            while (loopiteration < nofelement)
            {
                unknownvalues[i] = new List<int>();
                unknownvalues[i].Add((int)UWeights[stindx]);
                loopiteration++;
                stindx++;
            }
            loopiteration = 0;
        }
```

[this is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUVPG.jpg), it happened in the line of list of list
stindx,Noofelement and UWeights are correct

Is this the right way to define list of list and add to list of list?

```
List<List<int>> unknownvalues=new List<List<int>>();

unknownvalues[i] = new List<int>();
unknownvalues[i].Add((int)UWeights[stindx]);
```

Any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not checking if the array has enough elements. For instance, if the "Noofelement" array says 1, 2, 3, 4, then the total number of *required* elements are 10, you're not checking this. If the array only has 9 elements the last access will produce that error. There may be other similar sources of this exception in your code but that was the one I saw first.

Comment: Where does that [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) 4 come from?

Comment: Also, if `Noofelement` only has 3 or 2 or 1 elements, you'll get that error as well. Additionally you're creating a new list for each element. Can you please *debug* your code?

Comment: i want divide array into 4 parts !

Comment: Noofelement array is correct , if UWeights array contain 20 element then i am check the Noofelement acutally count 20 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unknownvalues` is being initialized as an empty list, and nothing is getting added into it, so `i` will always be outside the range of values that's in the list.

You can use `unknownvalues.Add(new List<int>())` instead of `unknownvalues[i] = new List<int>()`.